# Using Hibernate criteria fetch properties of two objects

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Getting Exception while running query using Criteria API

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: com of: com.data.Collage        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPathEntityName(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.createCriteriaEntityNameMap(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.<init>(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1550)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
```

Having class definitions as follow

```
class Collage {
int id;
String collageName;
List lstStudent;
}

class Student{
String studentName;
int id;
}
```

Have done mapping for above classes.

Now I am trying to fetch collage name and student name in single query where I have collageID and StudentID with me. Used Criteria API for this.

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria("com.data.Collage","collageAlias");
cr.createAlias("com.data.Student","studentAlias");
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("collageAlias.id", "402882c2369bc53901369bc95d5f0137"));
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("studentAlias.id","ff80808134cbe5a10134d14ff20300a9"));

ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.property("collageAlias.collageName"));
properties.add(Projections.property("studentAlias.studentName"));

cr.setProjection(properties);
List collage_student = cr.list();
```

I have try with Collage.class, removed alias name for collage as t's default class for criteria API, But it didn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Just a thought, since your fields are package private, they may not be accessible to your other code (if it's not in the same package). Try making them public or adding and getters and setters for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
cr.createAlias("com.data.Student","studentAlias");
```

Hibernate automatically thinks that Student is a field of the `Collage` class, as the criteria is built on that class. By creating an alias you automatically make a join on that particular entity.

Since your `Collage` class does not have a property named "com.data.Student" it causes your error.

You should consider refactoring your code a little bit. If you want the `Collage` to handle a list of `Student` entities, change `List lstStudent` to `List<Student> lstStudent`. Now, you can map the classes so that you tell Hibernate the relation between the 2 entities:

```
@Entity
class Collage {
    int id;
    String collageName;
    List<Student> lstStudent;
}

@Entity
class Student{
    String studentName;
    Collage collage;
    int id;
}
```

In the `Collage` class for the `List<Student> lstStudent` getter you will have:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "collage")
public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return this.lstStudents;
}
```

, while in the `Student` class for the getter of `Collage` you will have:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Collage getCollage(){
    return this.collage;
}
```

This basically allows you to create a Criteria on the `Collage` class and have direct access with an alias to its list of `Students`:

```
cr.createAlias("lstStudent", "studentsAlias");
```